# Unable to load mod_wsgi: Symbol not found: __Py_FalseStruct

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to install **mod_wsgi** (3.4) on my mac (mountain lion), I followed all the instructions here: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationInstructions but I'm unable to load that module due to the following error:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 119 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so, 10): Symbol not found: __Py_FalseStruct\n  Referenced from: /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so\n  Expected in: flat namespace\n in /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so
```

the message above is displayed by testing apache modules with:

```
apachectl -M
```

I have the default python mac install (2.7) plus the latest 3.3 manually installed using the dedicated dmg, when I ran `./configure` I tried by specifying both versions and adding the flag `--disable-framework` (which honestly I don't know what it does, but I found it mentioned in other discussions).

I'm stuck... what should I do?

**UPDATE:**

I configured mod_wsgi (with default python 2.7) by running:

```
make distclean
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

anyway I would like to use python 3.3, and fix the error I reported above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mod_wsgi` is a pain to install if you don't really know the bits and pieces that go along with it. At a guess, I'd say it has something to do with shared python libraries .Can I recommend using the [homebrew package manager](https://brew.sh) instead?

It's fairly straight forward installing brew, but installing mod_wsgi isn't anymore.

```
brew tap homebrew/apache
brew install mod_wsgi
```

Then follow the instructions after it completes. You'll have to change the directory where mod_wsgi is installed to.

A warning about homebrew though, you need to make sure you've got the latest version of XCode installed, or at least the xcode command line tools. Homebrew is great though.

Comment: does brew let me use python 3 easily? (since I finally installed mod_wsgi succesfully using python 2.7 as I wrote in the update)

Comment: I honestly don't know if brew way of installing mod_wsgi will let you specify the python used. I looked at the mod_wsgi page, and it mentions that the wsgi specification doesn't really support python 3 (but can be made to do so loosely by following a PEP). See https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/#System_Requirements I doubt brew will allow this, as it involves changing compiler flags.